# Ubuntu 22.04 fails to install

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

im facing an issue of installing ubuntu 22.04 on my HP laptop, now I've created the usb media which boots fine. starts the install but fails when its around 50% saying media is corrupt or a faulty hdd, hdd is brand new 1tb drive. Also have the same error with a  Kali linux media too both on different usb sticks, so i doubt its the usb sticks at fault. i have turned off uefi and secure boot but it still fails. Is there any fix for this

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Though your HDD is new, it could still be faulty. Have you confirmed the integrity of the HDD?